# Unable to stub current_or_guest_user in my helper specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a helper for ensuring that a user has permission to view a page, and redirects if the user doesn't have permission:

```
module PermissionsHelper
  def require_permission(permission_attribute_name)
    return if current_or_guest_user.role.send(permission_attribute_name)
    redirect_to current_or_guest_user.role.landing_page,
                notice: 'You do not have sufficient permissions'
  end
end
```

The method `current_or_guest_user` is a method I use in another helper that returns current user, or creates and returns a guest if there is no current user.

My spec looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PermissionsHelper, type: :helper do
  describe 'requiring permissions' do
    let(:test_user) { create :customer }

    it "redirects the user to the user's landing page if the user doesn't have permission" do
      allow(helper).to receive(:current_or_guest_user) { test_user }
      require_permission(:view_admins)
      expect(response).to redirect_to test_user.landing_page
    end
  end
end
```

And I am getting this error:

```
PermissionsHelper
  requiring permissions
    redirects the user to the user's langing page if the user doesn't have permission (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) PermissionsHelper requiring permissions redirects the user to the user's langing page if the user doesn't have permission
     Failure/Error: require_permission(:view_admins)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `current_or_guest_user' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PermissionsHelper::RequiringPermissions:0x007fb7b430afe8>
     # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:171:in `method_missing'
     # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/test_case.rb:271:in `method_missing'
     # ./app/helpers/permissions_helper.rb:3:in `require_permission'
     # ./spec/helpers/permissions_helper_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.0/lib/rspec/retry.rb:43:in `block (3 levels) in apply'
     # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.0/lib/rspec/retry.rb:34:in `times'
     # /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@project/gems/rspec-retry-0.4.0/lib/rspec/retry.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in apply'

Finished in 0.01188 seconds (files took 1.88 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/helpers/permissions_helper_spec.rb:9 # PermissionsHelper requiring permissions redirects the user to the user's langing page if the user doesn't have permission
```

EDIT: I tried changing `allow` to `allow_any_instance_of` and now I get this error:

With this spec:

```
it "redirects the user to the user's langing page if the user doesn't have permission" do
  allow_any_instance_of(helper).to receive(:current_or_guest_user) { test_user }
  require_permission(:view_admins)
  expect(response).to redirect_to test_user.landing_page
end
```

I get:

```
Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(helper).to receive(:current_or_guest_user) { test_user }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `ancestors' for #<#<Class:0x007fe5d19a9a98>:0x007fe5d19a1668>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allow
```

will only work with static methods.  Since the method in the helper is an instance method, you instead will want to use

```
allow_any_instance_of
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations/allow-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class

EDIT:

The below snippet fails in one of my projects (using the 'helper' variable)

```
allow_any_instance_of(helper).to receive(:paginate).and_return('asdf')
```

However, using the full class name works fine (for the purpose of testing method mocking at least)

```
allow_any_instance_of(PaginationHelper).to receive(:paginate).and_return('asdf)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct, because I've used allow on instance methods in the past and not had a problem. Either way I ran into an error with allow_any_instance_of and posted it in the original post.

Comment: I'm unsure what the purpose of 'helper' is in this rspec context, but it seems to behave as expected when using the proper class name.  I updated my post to reflect my meaning.

Comment: It's still not working. I am testing a helper, so I can't really say allow any instance of. I did try creating an anonymous class and making it include PermissionsHelper, but that didn't work either.